# Error when android studio creates a new project

Tags: android

I am using the latest version of android studio "chipmunk"; and JDK 11
Same error when creating new project multiple times

FAILURE: Build completed with 7 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.6.21/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.6.21/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21.pom'.
> > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
> > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

- Try:

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

[this is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J39lG.png)

Comment: can you share an image of the error

Comment: https://s2.loli.net/2022/05/31/Z3F1P84tSzdNc2y.png

Comment: There is no red error message in android studio, but when I run the project, the above error occurs

Comment: try to add this on your settings.gradle :

pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

Comment: ok, i'll try it now, thanks a lot

Comment: Unfortunately when I opened the file you said the code was already there；still it didn't work

Comment: I think it may be the problem of android studio, currently it is "Unable to obtain the resource file of the corresponding link"; but when I use Google to access the corresponding URL, I can view or download the corresponding file

Comment: I don't know how to reply to the specified person；I lowered the android studio version and successfully solved the problem;
This is my first time asking a question on Stack Overflow, thank you very much for your kindness

Comment: any other way except lowering down the version?